# pagination using javascript in php and mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, pagination

I am trying to do pagination using javascript but all in vain, please help..

```
<script language="Javascript">
function nextclicked()
{ 
document.getElementById("clickednext").value = document.getElementById("clickednext").value + 1;
document.forms["newsmanager"].submit();
}
</script>

<form name = "newsmanager" method="post" action="NewsManager.php">
<input type = "hidden"  id="clickednext" name="clickednext" > 


if(isset($_POST['clickednext']) && $_POST['clickednext']>=1)
{    
$_POST['clickednext'] = $_POST['clickednext'] +9; 
$NewsQuery = "SELECT NewsDetails FROM News LIMIT " .$_POST['clickednext']. ",10";
    }
    else
    {
    $NewsQuery  = "SELECT NewsDetails FROM News LIMIT 0,10";
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$NewsQuery);
}
```

**UPDATE :**

```
     <div class=d2 align=left>
<a  href="#" onclick=" nextclicked(); submit();" >
Next
</a>
```

**UPDATE ENDS......**

The first time when i click the Next hyperlink label, then it works, that is, 10 is assigned $_POST['clickednext'] and the next 10 values appear from the database, but the second time i  click the label , then it doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little algorithm I wrote using php to create pagination:

```
$x=$numStories;
$y=$x%5;
$z=($x-$y)/5;
if($y!=0){
    $numPages=$z+1;
}
else{
    $numPages=$z;
}
```

Where 5 is the number of stories per page, and `$numStories` is the total amount of stories (or in your case, news articles) you wish to use.

Then, just display the amount of pages (`$numPages`) in any way you'd like, and your good to go.

[EDIT]

I created an `archive.php` page, that took a page number as a GET parameter (`archive.php?page=3`). From there, I selected the first five entries in my database after `$pageNum` (in this case 3) * `10` (or however many posts per page you are wanting to display.

The best thing to do is make as much of your code dynamic and flexible, so that it is self sustaining.

[EDIT 2]

```
<script>
function nextclicked()
{ 
    document.forms["newsmanager"].submit();
}
</script>

<?php
    $currentPage = $_POST['page'];

    $numStories = //get the total amount of entries
    $x=$numStories;
    $y=$x%10;
    $z=($x-$y)/10;
    if($y!=0){
        $numPages=$z+1;
    }
    else{
        $numPages=$z;
    }

    if(isset($currentPage) && $currentPage>=1)
    {    
    $currentPage = $currentPage +9; 
    $NewsQuery = "SELECT NewsDetails FROM News LIMIT " .$currentPage. ",10";
        }
        else
        {
        $NewsQuery  = "SELECT NewsDetails FROM News LIMIT 0,10";
        }

        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$NewsQuery);
    }

?>

<form>
    <input type='hidden' name='page' text='' value='<?php echo "$currentPage"' />
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="nextClicked()">Next--></a>
```

Comment: see my edit, and if there is anything else you need explained, please be a little more specific

Comment: sir, i dont want to do anything with the URL, i just want to use javascript to do the pagination

Comment: in my code, the first time , the code runs successfully, that is, when the 1st time page is displayed then  0to10 records are shown , then, when i press the 'NEXT' hyperlink label, then , 10 to 20 records are displayed, but again the second time when i press the label, then nothing happens.....

Comment: Since you're submitting a form, add a hidden field with the value of the page you want to use, and use it as a POST parameter instead of a GET parameter. (it might not even have to be hidden, if you just want to display a textbox with the page number in it, and then allow the user to jump to a page that way)

Comment: its working the first time, because `$_POST['clickednext']` isn't changing. You need to make whatever that value is change whenever the page changes

Comment: sir, can you please rectify and help me in my code? am just stuck, cant solve it since last three hours

Comment: give me a little bit. I'll try and whip something up to add to this

Comment: @JordanForeman let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1667/discussion-between-sqlchild-and-jordan-foreman)

Comment: sir, please change 'next' to clickednext , it was a typos

Comment: i was using the value of hidden element "clickednext" , and incrementing it.

Comment: So do you need any more assistance?

Comment: yes sir, i have changed the post........there was no element named 'next' . everywhere was clickednext, i was incrementing its value and posting it on form submit, and then incrementing by 9 on every form submit

Comment: in your code, you have used 'next' , but you haven't defined it anywhere? what element is it? button or hidden element?

Comment: i want that, only on a single label click namely "Next" , the values displayed keep on changing , with the next 10 values displayed everytime the label is clicked.

Comment: sorry. Delete the line in the script that references 'next' and you should be good. Also, I forgot to edit your PHP to use the `$currentPage` variable. That is fixed

Comment: sir, you haven't mentioned any element, on clicking on which the displayed records would change? like a button or a label?

Comment: well I'm not going to write the entire page for you. I assumed you could integrate this into what you already have? Just add a link to do it then. `<a href="#" onclick="nextClicked()">Next--></a>`

Comment: sir, the value of $currentPage is always zero , how would it increment then?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is completely wrong.
You should scrap it and start all over again.
I will show you how to do so.

I have a rule when it comes to Ajax, and it goes like this.
**If you cannot do the functionality without Ajax, there's no way you should attempt to do it with Ajax.**

If you know anything about javascript, you'll know that XmlHttpRequest makes working with Ajax hellish. Hence why we have javascript frameworks such as JQuery and Mootools. You might also like a php ajax framework called PHPLiveX. I only use JQuery, so here's how to do the solution in JQuery.

**Step 1: Strip your ajax and create the solution in php**

[This pagination tutorial in php will help.](http://web.archive.org/web/20081015080344/http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/php-mysql-paging.php)

**Step 2a: Create the ajax with PHPLiveX**
PHPLiveX is really cool and underated, as it allows you to use php functions without reloading the whole page, in a more convienient way, than if you'd used javascript.

[PHPLiveX will help you the best.](http://phplivex.com/)
It's pretty straightforward. You call a php function to do something, return some values, and choose the target: of where you want the values to go.

I personally would use PHPLiveX for this job, as it's better suited. JQuery is more for postdata.

**Step 2b: Create the ajax in JQuery**

I'm going to assume that you know how to select elements by id with JQuery and append or replaceWith them. If not you can look the function up.

Below is the code required to submit a POST or GET with JQuery. Adapt this to your code. You'll have to modify the code below to add appending and stuff.

```
$(".tornfieldcard").click(function() {

    var dataString = $("#addfieldForm").serialize();
        //lets get the form data and use that
    var newValue = $("#newValue").val();
    var itemid4 = $(this).attr("itemid4");
    var dataString = "itemid=" + itemid + "&newValue=" + newValue;
        //or get the attr/valu from elements

    $("#loading5").show();
    $("#loading5").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="icons/loading.gif">');

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajaxcontrols.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){

    $("#loading5").remove();
    $(".fieldcardNEW").fadeOut('slow');
    $('.fieldcardNEW').remove();

    $("#conveyorbelt_"+itemid4+"").append("<div class=\"fieldcard\"><b>"+attribute+"</b>  <br><div itemid=\""+itemid4+"\" attribute=\""+attribute+"\">"+value+"</div></div>");
    }
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code is that your HTML is invalid. It's **not** `attribute=value`, it's `attribute="value"`. You're going to cause serious problems with Javascript and developer tools.


http://www.impressivewebs.com/dom-improperly-nested/

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server-side language. you have to put your php code to

```
<?php
```

=====

```
<script language="Javascript">
function nextclicked()
{ 
document.getElementById("next").value = document.getElementById("next").value + 1;
document.forms["newsmanager"].submit();
}
</script>

<form name = "newsmanager" method="post" action="NewsManager.php">
<input type = "hidden"  id="clickednext" name="clickednext" > 

<?php
if(isset($_POST['clickednext']) && $_POST['clickednext']>=1)
{    
$_POST['clickednext'] = $_POST['clickednext'] +9; 
$NewsQuery = "SELECT NewsDetails FROM News LIMIT " .intval($_POST['clickednext']). ",10";
    }
    else
    {
    $NewsQuery  = "SELECT NewsDetails FROM News LIMIT 0,10";
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$NewsQuery);
}
?>
```

additionally, user can't click to hidden form field. you need, for example button and have onclick event ready

```
<button name="next" value="1" onclick="nextclicked();">Next</button>
```

Comment: sir, what have you changed..i mean you have just added inval and nothing else..........will it work? what was wrong in my code?